# "command prompt here" context menu: how to uninstall it in windows7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I ran the MS powertoys to add a contextual menu "command prompt here" for easy command prompt access in Win7.

How can I get rid off it now ? 
There is a string to unistall it : c:\windows\rundll.exe setupx.dll,...

but this does not work on win7: do you lnow a way to remove that extra right click menu ?

regards

Comment: Run powertoys again...?

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't include MS DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Open Registry Editor as an Administrator.
Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell.
Look for an extra key, maybe DosHere.
Delete the extra key.

You should back up the registry beforehand, in case you accidentally delete the wrong key.

Comment: This is correct, but it's `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command]`